# Solving a polynomial in trigonometric functions

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

Given all variables are in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\{ a, d\} \neq 0$, solve for $\theta$:

$$a \sin^2 \theta + b \sin \theta + c + d \cos^2 \theta + e \cos \theta + f = 0$$

as posed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577312/solving-quadratic-function-of-sine-and-cosine#4577312).

The straightforward approach does not work:

```
Assuming[a != 0 \[And] b != 0,
 Solve[a Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + b Sin[\[Theta]] + c + d Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + 
    e Cos[\[Theta]] + f == 0, \[Theta]]]
```

One can force "smart" substitutions, as given in the solution to the linked source problem.  Is there a direct way to get the solution using *Mathematica*?

Comment: In practice I have found [Weierstraß substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) to be least problematic in terms of branch-cut problems. Yes it's not direct, but really works in practice. So, I'd just go with what the MathSE answer suggests.

Comment: @Roman:  Thanks.  Even the Weierstra$\beta$ substitution is rather awkward in *Mathematica*.  Is there really no other way?

Comment: `Solve[a Sin[θ]^2 + b Sin[θ] + c + d Cos[θ]^2 + e Cos[θ] + f == 0, θ, Quartics -> False]` does the substitutions for you (albeit less elegantly than Weierstraß) but of course still ends up with arctangents of the roots of a quartic polynomial. It uses the full-quadrant form of `ArcTan` in order to avoid branch cuts.

Comment: (ß is written in LaTeX as `\ss`, not as `\beta`) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ß

Comment: In the linked SE post, it is `a` and `d` that are non-zero, i.e., coefficients of the $\sin^2\theta$ and the $\cos^2\theta$ terms.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica has no trouble solving

```
eqn = a Sin[θ]^2 + b Sin[θ] + c + d Cos[θ]^2 + 
    e Cos[θ] + f == 0;

subs = {Sin[θ] -> sin, Cos[θ] -> cos};

solution = Solve[(eqn /. subs) && sin^2 + cos^2 == 1, {sin, cos}];
```

though the solution is rather large, and may not be useful to you.

Comment: Gee... that is a *LARGE* solution.  Thanks, though ($+1$).

Answer (score 1):

I think Weirstaß-substitution isn't "awkward" and gives a clear direct solution:

Transforming the equation using Weirstaß-substitution `\[Theta] -> 2 ArcTan[u\[Theta]]` gives

```
eqW = a Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + b Sin[\[Theta]] + c + d Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + 
e Cos[\[Theta]] + f /. \[Theta] -> 2 ArcTan[u\[Theta]] // TrigExpand // Collect[#, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, Simplify] &
```

$$
\frac{4 a \text{u$\theta $}^2}{\left(\text{u$\theta$}^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{2 b \text{u$\theta $}}{\text{u$\theta$}^2+1}+c+\frac{d \left(\text{u$\theta$}^2-1\right)^2}{\left(\text{u$\theta$}^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{e \left(1-\text{u$\theta$}^2\right)}{\text{u$\theta $}^2+1}+f
$$

Mathematica

```
Solve[eqW == 0, u\[Theta], Reals] /. u\[Theta] -> Tan[\[Theta]/2];
```

finds four solutions in the form of Root objects

`{Tan[\[Theta]/2] ->Root[c + d + e + f + 2 b #1 + (4 a + 2 c - 2 d + 2 f) #1^2 +  2 b #1^3 + (c + d - e + f) #1^4 &, 1]}`

Solutions are lengthy.